# list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType

Tags: python

I was dealing with this problem when I am trying to create quick sort on my own
I don't know how to fix the error and I most certainly do not know if any other problem exists in my code.

```
def Qsort(list):
    if len(list) < 2:
        return list
    Qsorthelper(list, 0, len(list)-1)

def Qsorthelper(list, first, last):
    if last>first:
        split=partition(list, first, last)
        Qsorthelper(list, first, split-1)
        Qsorthelper(list, split+1, last)

def median(list):
    if len(list) %2 == 0:
        return (len(list)//2+len(list)//2-1)/2
    else:
        return len(list)//2

def finditem(list, num):
    for i in range(0,len(list)-1):
        if num == list[i]:
            return i


def choosepivot(list):
    if list[0] > list[len(list)-1] > list[median(list)] or list[0] < 
    list[len(list)-1] < list[median(list)]:
        return list[len(list)-1]
    elif list[len(list)-1] > list[0] > list[median(list)] or 
    list[len(list)-1] < list[0] < list[median(list)]:
        return list[0]
    else:
        return list[median(list)]



def partition(list, first, last):
    pivot = choosepivot(list)
    list.append(pivot)
    list.remove(pivot)
    left = list[first]
    right = list[last-1]
    done = False

    while not done:
        while left <= right and list[left] <= pivot:
            left = left + 1

        while right >= left and list[right] >= pivot:
            right = right - 1

        if right < left:
            done = True
        else:
            temp = list[left]
            list[left] = list[right]
            list[right] = temp

    temp = list[finditem(list,pivot)]
    list[finditem(list,pivot)] = list[right]
    list[right] = temp

    return right

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
Qsort(alist)
print(alist)
```

I don't know what is the problem that caused the error but I really want to fix it
any suggestions or answers?

edit:
I changed the finditem part to fix the i not finding the last element:

```
def finditem(alist, num):
    for i in range(0,len(alist)):
        if num == alist[i]:
            return i
```

and I got this error:

```
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ITB\failed quick sort.py", line 59, in partition
    alist[finditem(alist,pivot)] = alist[right]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> 

temp = list[finditem(list,pivot)]
list[finditem(list,pivot)] = list[right]
list[right] = temp
```

this ipart is the part where I switch the final item with the pivot to complete one cycle, something is wrong here but I want to know how.

Comment: Please add the error message to your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python error “list indices must be integers not Nonetype”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417159/python-error-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-nonetype)

Comment: well... too many lines of code to debug. Maybe you can isolate it a bit more? Also: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, the error must be indicating which line of code is returning the error. To help, I would `print the list after every operation with it` and see if it is returning what is expected. Then you can be more precise where something is going wrong. (Tip, add a number to each print to easy the task, as in `print("Step 1. " , list)` )

Comment: Your code has several errors. It would be much better if you test your code after every step you write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code causing the mentioned error is in your `finditem` function, which stops before the last element. If the item you are trying to find happens to be the last element, None is returned, and is used as an index for `list` (You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, since it has another meaning in python).

This isn't the only problem though. The `median` function can also return floats, so anything indexing with it (like this `list[median(list)]`) could fail for even sized lists.

There are additional errors as well. I would recommend testing each function individually, and perhaps looking at some existing implementations for guidance.